# Problem with a \textquote that ends with an itemize

Tags: itemize, csquotes

How to use `\textquote` if the quoted sentence ends with an itemized list?

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[autopunct=true]{csquotes}

\begin{document}
Ducks quack \textquote{something:
\begin{itemize}
\item blah 
\item blah.
\end{itemize}}\footnote{A note}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For such special case you should probably use the direct quote commands:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[autopunct=true]{csquotes}

\begin{document}
Ducks quack \textooquote something:
\begin{itemize}
\item blah
\item blah.\textcoquote\footnote{A note}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

An alternative is an inline list:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[autopunct=true]{csquotes}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\begin{document}
Ducks quack \textquote{something:
\begin{itemize*}
\item blah
\item blah.
\end{itemize*}}\footnote{A note}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The first one is perfect, I can't use inline list because the actual item texts are longer than in the MWE.